# Where does the gluteus medius attach to the greater trochanter compared to the gluteus minimus attachment?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, muscles, tendons

Where does the gluteus medius attach to the greater trochanter of the femur  compared to the gluteus minimus attachment? Is it above, below, next to it, etc.? Ideally I'd like to know the distance as well and location relative to the greater trochanter.

---

What I have found so far: some diagrams place the gluteus medius attachment *below* the gluteus minimus attachment, some place it *above* and some place it next to it at the *same height*.

Example of diagram placing the gluteus medius attachment *below* the gluteus minimus attachment ([image source](https://mikereinold.com/gluteus-medius-evaluation-strengthening/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190422082847/https://mikereinold.com/gluteus-medius-evaluation-strengthening/))):

[image]

Example of diagram placing the gluteus medius attachment *next to* the gluteus minimus attachment ([image source](https://nashvillehip.org/abductor-tendons-gluteus-medius-minimus-injury/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190422082608/https://nashvillehip.org/abductor-tendons-gluteus-medius-minimus-injury/)))

[image]

Example of diagram placing the gluteus medius attachment *above* the gluteus minimus attachment ([image source](http://muscular-system.blogspot.com/2013/05/gluteal-muscles.html?m=1) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190422082753/http://muscular-system.blogspot.com/2013/05/gluteal-muscles.html?m=1))):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{1} greatly answers the question.

Regarding the insertion location (lateral view):

[image]

Note that unlike the gluteus minimus insertion, the gluteus medius insertion can also be viewed anterolaterally:

[image]

Table 2 contains more detailed insertion location data:

[image]

Regarding the insertion area:

[image]

> - Gluteus maximus: Average Area, mm^2 (95% CI): 473.4 (381.0, 565.8). Thick, muscular insertion along the posterior femur on the linea aspera
> - Gluteus medius: Composed of 2 contiguous rectangular footprints, the lateral facet oriented in the sagittal plane and the superomedial facet primarily in the transverse plane:
>
>   - Lateral facet: Average Area, mm^2 (95% CI): 141.1 (117.7, 164.5).
>   - Superomedial facet: Average Area, mm^2 (95% CI): 501.5 (442.8, 560.2).
> - Gluteus minimus: Average Area, mm^2 (95% CI):  280.9 (229.3, 332.5). Two morphologies noted: The majority (11/14) were long, thin, and crescent shaped and ran medial to lateral and concave facing inferiorly, while a few (3/14) were bowtie in shape.

Below are some actual pictures of the gluteus minimus insertion, the gluteus medius insertion to get another sense of their shape and location. Still  from {1}, this picture shows the gluteus medius (but not the gluteus minimus):

[image]

From {2}, this picture shows both the gluteus medius muscle and the gluteus minimus muscle:

[image]

I also find this picture good to give a better sense as to where the greater trochanter is located with respect to the human body ([image source](http://anatomy.medicine.yale.edu/Lab_12/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190422225842/http://anatomy.medicine.yale.edu/Lab_12/))):

[image]

---

References:

- {1} Philippon, Marc J., Max P. Michalski, Kevin J. Campbell, Mary T. Goldsmith, Brian M. Devitt, Coen A. Wijdicks, and Robert F. LaPrade. "Surgically relevant bony and soft tissue anatomy of the proximal femur." Orthopaedic journal of sports medicine 2, no. 6 (2014): 2325967114535188. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Surgically+Relevant+Bony+and+Soft+Tissue+Anatomy+of+the+Proximal+Femur&btnG= ; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26535335 ; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4555602/ ; https://doi.org/10.1177/2325967114535188
- {2} Woodley, Stephanie J., Susan R. Mercer, and Helen D. Nicholson. "Morphology of the bursae associated with the greater trochanter of the femur." JBJS 90, no. 2 (2008): 284-294. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Morphology+of+the+Bursae+Associated+with+the+Greater+Trochanter+of+the+Femur&btnG= ; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18245587 ; https://doi.org/10.2106/JBJS.G.00257