# For each movement performed by both the gluteus minimus and medius, what percentage of the movement do the gluteus minimus and medius account for?

Tags: human-anatomy, muscles, anatomy

From what I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gluteus_minimus&oldid=870819031#Function), all functions of the gluteus minimus are mirrored by the gluteus medius. Additionally, the gluteus medius is larger than the gluteus minimus (see comparative images [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/82887/630)), which leads me to believe that the gluteus medius is stronger than the gluteus minimus. I wonder to what extent it is stronger.

For each movement performed by both the gluteus minimus and the gluteus medius, what percentage of the movement do the gluteus minimus and the gluteus medius account for, respectively? (e.g., 80% of the strength stemmed from the gluteus medius, and 20% of the strength stemmed from the gluteus medius)